# Android VideoView is not working for online video streaming

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-videoview

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_s);
    VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
    String vidAddress = "VideoURL";
    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
    vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
    vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
    vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
```

Activity was launched successfully but unable to play the video.

Comment: 'Unable to play the video'; Could you elaborate on this? Are you getting any error messages in your log?

Comment: Thanks alot Mdlc for looking up! There isn't any error message but its just blank rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
vidView.start();
```

You have to include this permissions on AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You could try 3rd party library like:
[easy-video-player](https://github.com/afollestad/easy-video-player)

Comment: Thank you so much Andres but can you tell me what mVV.start() stands for? its giving me error. Should I write vidView.start? Also, the video is of mp4 format. Is it Okay?

Comment: Sorry is vidView.start();

Comment: Hey Andres, It worked Finally! May God bless you! Just one problem. Its too much slow! How can we make it faster?

Comment: The video streaming depends of a lot of variables to be fast such as Video Size, video quality, internet access speed, bandwidth of your server.... But I strongly recommend use a lib to help android making this process, you may try: https://github.com/afollestad/easy-video-player

Comment: Sure! I'll try that Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might also want to look at something like [ExoMedia](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia) which handles more formats than the stock `MediaPlayer` (which easy-video-player wraps)